# How to check if less than 'n' numbers were input into an array containing of size n?

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code. This will keep asking for a user's input n times until all 'n' elements in the array are full. I want to make it such that if a user doesn't enter a value (i.e. the 
'n' element array doesn't have n elements in it) then it will return 0. Thanks

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){

    scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    if(**check condition here**) {
        return 0; 
    }
}

return 1;
```

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf` (look up the documentation to see what it returns)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `scanf` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ states:

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled

So check the return value:

```
int items = scanf("%d", &array[n]);
if( items == 1 ) {
    // was read
}
else {
    // no input
}
```

There's a bug in your code: you're always setting `array[n]` without incrementing `n`. I think you should change it to `&array[i]`.

Comment: Ah yeah it should be array[i]. Thanks!